# Write-Ordering Problem, Idempotency in Distributed File Systems

Tags: operating-systems, distributed-systems, computer-networks, concurrency, filesystems

I have recently finished reading the section on Distributed Systems in OSTEP. For NFS, they briefly mention the cache consistency problem and say how it is solved for reads by maintaining an attribute cache (though there will be inconsistency if any reads occur between attribute updates) and that for writes it is "solved" by a `close()` function forcing writes to secondary storage.

Assume two clients, one server. Consider this:

- Client A writes to File X at Time 1
- Client B writes to File X at Time 2
- Client B closes File X (write forced)
- Client A closes file X (write forced)

So Client A's changes are stored, though they happened earlier. Is this problem addressed by NFS? How can it otherwise be solved?

I have thought of a possible solution of server-side checking last modified time, but what about clock skew on a client?

I have one other slightly unrelated, but related question. The book mentions that something like `MKDIR` is not idempotent, so if the client retries after server success (but the message was lost on the way back to the client) then they receive a false error response. How can this be addressed? Is it on the client to then explicitly check on failures for `mkdir()` to see if the sub-directory then exists?